# Is it possible to replace/modify Implicit style at run time xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

I have the need to replace at runtime an implicit style that is located in a merged resource dictionary

for example lets suppose I have

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
</Style>
```

Now I want to replace the all style with something else at runtime. Can this be done?

Above is just a sample.. Nothing todo with theming or anything else, I have the need to replace the all implicit style at runtime.

Can I detect based on TargetType ?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like [theming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes)

Comment: Actually in this occasion I need to change some fontsizes at runtime based on whether is a small device or not

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think that [data triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#data-triggers) might help you. For example, you can change `FontSize` with something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding isSmallDevice}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Given that "IsSmallDevice " is living in the app.xaml will the styles that is part of the MergedDictionary be able to see it? As you can imagine I dont want the datatrigger scattered all over

Answer (score 0):

> Actually in this occasion I need to change some fontsizes at runtime based on whether is a small device or not

You can use [OnIdiom markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming) to detect Phone or Table or desktop.

```
 <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <OnIdiom
                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                Phone="18"
                                Tablet="50" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>                   
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
```